# What is a quick ticket?

Tags: mario-kart-tour

I have a challenge that says to use one quick ticket. I have used ones that give me items, various ones to upgrade drivers or karts or gliders, but none of those seem to be a quick ticket.

What is a quick ticket and how do I get one?

Comment: [how to get them](https://www.gamerevolution.com/guides/602743-what-is-mario-kart-tour-quick-ticket) and how to use them [article](https://gamerjournalist.com/how-to-use-quick-tickets-in-mario-kart-tour/), [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12pSKJKF3Ko)

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Sentry I didn’t want to post it as an answer because summarizing an article feels like too low effort to deserve votes. I also don’t have the ability right now to download the game to write an answer that fills in the gaps in the understanding that I have after only checking out those source

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 If you find the time, don't be afraid to do it. One of the goals of the stackexchange network is to be self-contained. The websites you linked might go offline in the future, so summarizing them in a concise answer is what this site is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain cups are time-gated when added to the game, meaning you must wait a set amount of time before the cup becomes playable. A quick ticket is used to bypass this waiting period and grant you instant access to the cup. You can use the ticket from the cup selection screen when you have selected a cup which is currently under construction.